# Which opensource NoSQL DB/DataStore has a good Visualization tool also?

Tags: open-source, nosql, data-visualization

I have been running around here and there on NoSQL big data storage technologies. The greatest hurdle I have found so far is a good visualization tool. With out that, it seems so hard to understand how data is being kept in the storage. This would be a generalized question but I would need to know which NoSQL storage technologies either comes with a visualization tool or an open source contribution that has been proven to be great. The tool shows nodes,database tables and entries as well.

I hope people who have experience against would share their hard earned knowledge.

Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org). It has got visualization tool developed on top of eclipse code base.